How to fill multiple rows Entity Framework in Select
How can I fill out a list of companies with a request of this type?
The include method does not work in my implementation
   var list = await (from d in context.User.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.UserId))
                          from c in context.Company.Where(x => x.UserId == d.UserId)
                          select new User()
                          {
                             UserId = d.UserId
                             Companies = c.Select(x => new Company() {}) // - need Lists
                          }).ToListAsync(token);


Just to be clear, you want to find a User by ID and then include the companies he is in?

Yes, that's the point. But I want to do this in one request

With context.User.Include(u=>u.Companies).Where(u=>ids.Contains(u.Id).ToListAsync(). EF isn't a database driver, it deals with entities, not rows, and LINQ queries load entire graphs of related objects at a time. If you have to use JOINs to match related entities, the User and Company classes are wrong and the DbContext lacks the proper relations

just do context.User.Include(a=>a.Company).Where(x => ids.Contains(x.UserId)).select(b=>b) and u will have also the companies in each selected user.

If you use proper naming conventions you won't even have to specify the relations. If User has  public List<Company> Companies{get;set;} or public Company Company {get;set;} properties, EF will infer the relations between user and Company and generate the JOIN itself. If the key columns match conventions, eg Id UserId for User, Id or CompanyId for the Company, it won't even have to be told which properties are the keys

@Panagiotis Kanavos this will work if there is a foreign key established between entities... and I did the same assumption that it is.... otherwise he will have to use DTOs...

@DA no, the FK doesn't matter at all. FKs are constraints, not relations. The JOIN can be generated as long as the columns are there

In EF 7 and later EF can infer many-to-many relations too without having to create a bridge entity. If there's a User.Companies and Company.Users, EF will infer there's a UserCompanies table and include it in the JOIN without requiring a UserCompany type

If you want to fetch the user and his companies, I suggest you try this statement
var user = await context.User
  .Where(user => user.Id == userId)
  .Include(user => user.Companies)
  .ToListAsync(token);

var companies = user.Companies;

Using LINQ here is in my opinion a better way to query the database.
Be sure you define a ICollection<Company> Companies in your user, then this navigation should work.
